# Solutions in Mathematica NSolve

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Mathematica NSolve returns a solution in the form: {var1-->num1, var2-->num2}.  How do I assign those solutions to variables automatically?  I want var1=num1 and var2=num2, from which I can then process var1 and var2 as needed.  Currently I am forced to hand enter the solution before proceeding with subsequent computations using the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is Wolfram's tutorial on exactly this subject.

[Applying Transformation Rules](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ApplyingTransformationRules.html)

Here is a one-line example

```
{x, y} = {x, y} /. NSolve[{x + y == 3, x - y == -1}, {x, y}][[1]]
```

which assigns 1 to x and 2 to y.

Comment: What is the purpose of the [[1]] at the end? Without it, the operation fails.

Comment: If you read the help pages for NSolve you see that it returns {{solution1}} if there is only one solution or {{solution1},{solution2}} if there are two, etc. Since my example only had one solution and I wanted the values from that single solution I used [[1]] to extract the first solution from the list. Look up Part or [[ in the help system to see how this works.